# Configuring VOIP server without SIP

Tags: vpn, voip

So I want to create a VOIP server with that I can connect with OpenVPN so I can call only a number of people that are in my network. I'll be using CSIPSIMPLE for that purpose. I'll be using only internet calls without calling SIM cards.

My question is can I do this without trunks. I'm kind of new to the telephony industry and don't understand why I will need a trunk when I'll be using only IP calls but everywhere I read they say buy a trunk.

Also some decent reading for VOIP with VPN would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a trunk, you will only be able to call extensions on your pbx - no matter what client you use.

A lot of people are using Google voice as a trunk for their FreePBX VoIP servers.

For more info about VoIP with a general overview, http://www.voip-info.org/ has some handy tutorials to get you started.